# Pregunta de sintaxis JS ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

tengo un pequeño problema de sintaxis , el siguiente codigo tiene una variable contador declarada fuera de la funcion, al momento de escanear la array , deberia transformarme el contador a 1 pero cuando hago un console.log fuera de la funcion ajax sigue en 0

adjunto codigo

```
 var contador=0;

  $.ajax({
    url: "validar_rut_alias.php",
    dataType:"json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        

        $.each(data, function(id, nombre) {
                
                if(nombre.alias==$("#alias").val()){
                    alert("El alias ya esta registrado");
                    contador=1;
                }
                else if(nombre.rut==$("#rut").val()){
                    alert("El rut ya esta registrado");
                    contador=1;
                }
                

        });
        
        
        
        
        
    });
if(contador>0){
    return false;
}
```

contador se mantiene en 0 , pero

```
alert("El alias ya esta registrado");
```

si aparece en la pagina, entonces no se donde me estoy confundiendo.
Nota: el console log se hace despues del ultimo if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me hace conocido tu nombre...

Esta es la lógica que interpreta JS.

1. Crea una variable que se llama contador
2. Invoca una llamada HXR, es decir Ajax.
3. Evalúa el contador

Un poco más práctico sería, estas haciendo una sopa y necesitas 2 papas, pero no tienes, así que mandas a tu hijo al mercado por 2 papas, pero justo cuando lo mandas te preguntas si ya tienes 2 papas, pero tu hijo aún no regresa. Así funciona una invocación asíncrona.

Arreglaría un poco tu código ya que no estas usando todas las bondades de ES6

```
<script>
    const validarRut = async () => {
        let contador  = 0;
        const ajax    = {};
        ajax.url      = 'validar_rut_alias.php';
        ajax.dataType = 'json';

        try {
            const result = await $.ajax( ajax );
            const alias = $('#alias').val().trim();
            const rut   = $('#rut').val().trim();
            
            result.data.map( ( nombre ) => {
                if (nombre.alias === alias || nombre.rut === rut) {
                    contador += 1;
                }
            });

        return !(contador > 0);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Ocurrió un error ', e);
        }
    };

    const registrado = validarRut();
    console.log( 'Esta registrado', registrado );
</script>
```

Comment: en algunos casos me sale [object promise] , cuando intento de realizar la consulta